# Change capistrano chmod task to deploy magento application

Tags: magento2, capistrano

we have a capistrano for our magento application

The deploy are working fine from `tools/cap/config/deploy.rb` and run correctly each specific env we have like for example `tools/cap/config/deploy/production.rb`

The problem is that during the deploy process we would like to change the chmod command made by capistrano cause this is getting us some trouble we need to setup manually the rights after each deploy.

We clearly see in the `capistrano.log`

```
INFO [db28dba5] Running /usr/bin/env find /var/www/ourwebsite/web/releases/20201117160947 -type f ! -perm 660 -exec chmod 660 {} + as domain@ip
```

So that chmod 660 must be defined somewhere...but I can't find where.

So I'm looking into a way to "extend" that capistrano behaviour...or at least to add a specific tasks at the end of the current deploy process that will do what we want.

I've seen there was a way to define specific tasks cause we got this in our `Capfile`

```
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

But currently we didn't get any of them.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please give full permissions to the root directory of your magento web site. Please give the highest permission (use 777 permission)